# How can I return all h1´s with the class fluid

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code below must generate a list which contains all the h1 which contain the class fluid. But it returns an empty list. I cannot find the mistake, can anyone help me

```
allh1= soup.findAll('h1')

classes = [ h1.get('class') for h1 in allh1]
fluid_list = []
for item in classes:
    if item == 'fluid':
        fluid_list.append(item)

print fluid_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your `classes` list contains a list of lists of the classes for each `h1` found (or `None` if there is no class):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<h1 class="fluid">header 2</h1>
<h1>header 3</h1>
<h1 class="fluid static">header 4</h1>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

allh1= soup.findAll('h1')
classes = [ h1.get('class') for h1 in allh1]
print(classes)

[None, ['fluid'], None, ['fluid', 'static']]
```

If you're using Beautiful Soup 4.1.2+, you can use `class_`, however:

```
fluid_list = soup.find_all('h1', class_='fluid')
print fluid_list

[<h1 class="fluid">header 2</h1>, <h1 class="fluid static">header 4</h1>]
```

This returns the `h1` elements themselves, which I assume is what you want.